# In SQL, is there an alternative way to see if a record is already there before adding it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this,

```
id (primary key) | name | scores
```

and I am reading a large file to insert records into the MySQL table.

New records will be added into this file but the old records are not deleted, so when I read the file, a lot of records are already in the database.

Except to use SELECT COUNT to see if a record is already in the database, is there a best way to check it (to save processing time & database load)?

Or maybe I should just INSERT it directly? (The database will not allow records with duplicate id anyway.)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I would likely use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: You need to consider concurrency. Checking first and then inserting is only thread-safe inside a transaction. It's generally best just to define the appropriate unique keys and attempt the insertion and cope with the failure if any, rather than try to guess ahead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use update + insert method.

first i will run the update statement. the update query will act like a select query + directly update the data.

```
update t1 set t1.Name = 'Name', t1.Scores = 99
where t1.Name = 'Name' and t1.Scores = 99
```

then check if there is a row affected by the above query. if not run the insert statement

```
if @@RowCount = 0
 insert into t1 (Name, Scores) values ('Name',99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Serch examples for

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table
```

Simple example for this is

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `transcripts`
SET `ensembl_transcript_id` = ‘ENSORGT00000000001′,
`transcript_chrom_start` = 12345
`transcript_chrom_end` = 12678;
```