# How to write a stored procedure for insert value into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Two Tables

```
tblClass  - ClassID {PK} , ClassName
tblOperation - OperationID {PK} , OperationName , ClassId
```

From Client Side these parameters are coming:

```
 @OperationName VARCHAR ,
 @ClassName VARCHAR  ,
 @UserID int
```

I want to first check tblClass and if class name is not there class name should add to the table.

After that want to check tblOperation and check class id and operation name if it is not there have to insert. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: I have tried If else conditions but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ClassCount AS TINYINT,
DECLARE @OperationCount AS TINYINT,
DECLARE @ClassID AS BIGINT

SELECT @ClassCount = COUNT(ClassName), @ClassID = ClassID  FROM tblClass WHERE ClassName = @ClassName 

IF(@ClassCount = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblClass VALUES (@ClassName)
SELECT ClassID FROM tblClass WHERE ClassName = @ClassName
END

SELECT @OperationCount = COUNT(OperationName) FROM tblOperation WHERE OperationName = @OperationName

IF(@OperationCount = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblOperation VALUES (@OperationName,@ClassID)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you will be checking for if the value exists, then update it and if it doesn't, then insert it.

Here is some starter code to get you on your way :) I haven't done the whole thing for you.

Manipulate the below to get what you are looking for.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE NameOfStoredProc 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @OperationName VARCHAR ,
     @ClassName VARCHAR  ,
     @UserID int
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT ClassName FROM  tblClass WHERE ClassName = @ClassName)
BEGIN
    --UPDATE HERE
    --UPDATE TblClass SET ClassID = ###, ClassName = ### WHERE ?
    --UPDATE TblOperation SET OperationID  = ###, OperationName  = ###, ClassId - ### WHERE ?
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- INSERT HERE
   --INSERT INTO tblClass
   --INSERT INTO tblOperation
END
```

Comment: the update query can act as select query, to check the record existence, visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431489/in-sql-is-there-an-alternative-way-to-see-if-a-record-is-already-there-before-a/22431743#22431743

Comment: @Cyan... That's very cool, Learn something new each day right.  :) Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertClassOperation
   @OperationName VARCHAR(100),
   @ClassName VARCHAR(100),
   @UserID INT

AS

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblClass WHERE ClassName = @ClassName)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tblClass(ClassName) VALUES (@ClassName)
   DECLARE @ClassId INT = (SELECT ClassId FROM tblClass WHERE ClassName = @ClassName)

   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblOperation WHERE OperationName = @OperationName AND ClassId = @ClassId)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tblOperation(OperationName, ClassId) VALUES (@ClassId)
   END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this concept:

1. run update query in the tblClass

   update tblclass set... where classname = 'something'
2. check if there is any row affected, if no row affected run the insert query

   if @@RowCount = 0 
   insert into tblclass (...) values (....)
3. next run the update query for tblOperation

   update tblOperation set classId = @@Identity, ... where bla bla bla
4. check if there is any row affected, if no row affected run the insert query

   if @@RowCount = 0
   insert into tblOperation (...,classId) values (...,@@Identity)

visit [In SQL, is there an alternative way to see if a record is already there before adding it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431489/in-sql-is-there-an-alternative-way-to-see-if-a-record-is-already-there-before-a/22431743#22431743) for further information